# run tests within Docker container via Gradle

Tags: docker, unit-testing, gradle

I have specific unit tests that require system changes. I want to encapsulate system changes inside the docker container and run tests there, so no one will need to change their local configuration to run tests.

How to do that via Gradle?

For my project, I use Gradle version 7.4.2 and Java 17.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I might focus on splitting your test suite into _unit_ tests that require nothing beyond the JVM and _system_ tests that work with the installed system.  Trying to write a build-time test that simulates complex system configurations will become hard to debug (and hopefully your code isn't _that_ sensitive to what else is installed in its environment).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need gradle (I have no experience with it), I run systemd and salt tests with podman using simple bash wrappers - then you can include those if needed into Makefile or any CI or gradle or whatever.

One of recent examples: https://github.com/andrii-suse/mirrorcache-formula/blob/main/.github/workflows/t.yaml#L14

Comment: Gradle is already integrated into our CI flow, so it would be much simpler to use the same stack for this. In your solution, you copy all related files as well as tests to the podman container by bash and run tests there, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Until recently I would have said [Batect](https://batect.dev/) is the tool of choice to use, but unfortunately the project is [not maintained anymore](https://batect.dev/blog/2023/10/22/batect-is-no-longer-maintained/). Though is it working, still.